# How to get all childs of a issue of the gira, using method GET from api rest

Tags: rest, get, jira, jql

I'm trying to get all the children of a task in Jira using the jql from gira, but I can't find a way to pass the jql in the get method. I made progress in passing a jql that references a project but not the children of a task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"All childs of an issue" means "all subtasks under the issue" and you can get all subtasks by getting the issue object.

Just send one **GET** request to `/rest/api/2/issue/{issueKey}` which returns you a `JSON` object.

In this JSON object, there are a "`fields`" object which contains "`subtasks`" array.

Each element of subtasks array contains issue keys for each subtask/child of an issue. Also, it contains some other basic system fields (e.g. summary, assignee) for each issue.

After getting the subtasks, again you can send a `GET` request to the same endpoint with each subtask's issue key (`/rest/api/2/issue/{subTasksIssueKey}`) and you can get all the fields and details for each subtask.