# Jira REST API: Get issue does not return any subtasks (children)

Tags: jira

I'm using the Jira Rest API and I want to read in a parent/child hierarchy. To do this, I read in the top element and then wanted to reload the children from the JSON via subtasks. Unfortunately, subtasks is always empty - not even with the parameter `?expand=children`.

See also: [How to get all childs of a issue of the gira, using method GET from api rest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73158038/17843115)

Here is my API call: https://jira.mydomain.de/rest/api/2/issue/CANVAS15-219?expand=children.

Attached is the screenshot of the issue in Jira. There you can see four child elements:

[image: Jira issue with children]

**What do I have to do to read the child elements via the Rest API?**

The JSON response (abbreviated):

```json
{
  "expand": "renderedFields,names,schema,operations,editmeta,changelog,versionedRepresentations",
  "id": "6943669",
  "self": "https://jira.mydomain.de/rest/api/2/issue/6943669",
  "key": "CANVAS15-219",
  "fields": {
    "customfield_48448": null,
    ...
    "customfield_48478": null,
    "subtasks": [],
    "customfield_48475": null,
    ...
    "customfield_12810": null
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Epics don't have subtasks. Subtasks live inside their Issue, while what shows up in the UI as an epic's "child issues" are really top-level Issue items themselves.

So to find all the issues under a given epic, you have to query against all issues using the "Epic Link" field (which is a custom field whose ID you'll have to look up so you can translate it into the JSON field name). Then you can do something like this to find the issues under the epic:

```
/rest/api/3/search?jql=customfield_xxxxx=CANVAS15-219
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.
In my case it work with the call https://jira.telekom.de/rest/api/2/search?'jql=%22Parent%20Link%22=CANVAS15-219